# function template specialization for inheritance

Tags: c++11, inheritance, overloading

In C++11, I implement function template specialization for identifying inheritance, but it occurred compile-time errors.

`f()` checks whether the specified class is derived from `Base` or not.

Following is a source code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

struct Base {};
struct Derived : Base {};
struct Base2 {};

template<typename T, bool = std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value>
void f() {
    cout << "T is not Base or Base-derived class." << endl;
};

template<typename T>
void f<T, true>() {
    cout << "T is Base or Base-derived class." << endl;
};

int main() {
    f<Base>();    // ok
    f<Derived>(); // ok
    f<Base2>();   // not ok
    return 0;
}
```

Following is error messages.

```
prog.cpp:15:17: error: non-class, non-variable partial specialization 'f<T, true>' is not allowed
 void f<T, true>() {
                 ^
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:20:13: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
     f<Base>();
             ^
prog.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Base; bool <anonymous> = true]
 void f() {
      ^
prog.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Base]
 void f<T, true>() {
      ^
prog.cpp:21:16: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
     f<Derived>();
                ^
prog.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Derived; bool <anonymous> = true]
 void f() {
      ^
prog.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Derived]
 void f<T, true>() {
      ^
prog.cpp:22:14: error: call of overloaded 'f()' is ambiguous
     f<Base2>();
              ^
prog.cpp:10:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Base2; bool <anonymous> = false]
 void f() {
      ^
prog.cpp:15:6: note: candidate: void f() [with T = Base2]
 void f<T, true>() {
      ^
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value` evaluates `true` you have two functions with same signature. Therefore you get error "call ... is amibguous".

Try simple overloading as one of the solutions:

```
namespace detail {
    void doIt(std::false_type) {
        cout << "T is not Base or Base-derived class." << endl;
    };
    void doIt(std::true_type) {
        cout << "T is Base or Base-derived class." << endl;
    };
}

template<typename T>
void f() {
    detail::doIt(typename std::is_base_of<Base, T>::type());
};
```

Of course the function `detail::doIt()` can be more complex and templated by T.

EDIT: add `"detail::"` into a function `f()` call.

Comment: I should specify `using namespace detail;`, but except it, it works great. Thanks!